# Is there a way to simplify naming of elements from a graphql query map function with nextjs?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, next.js, graphql

I'm new to next.js and graphql. I'm currently building an app off a WordPress site's graphql endpoint. One thing that's kind of annoying is having to type out the information's "path" from the graphql query. I'm used to making a list of simple variables in PHP to minimize typing. A basic example would be `$title = get_the_title();` in WordPress. Then i'd carry on with other variables like `$url, $img, $author`. I want to know if there is a way to do this in next.js?

Here's an example of something I'm messing around with:

```
export default function WorkGrid({ work, className = 'content-section has-tinted-background my-work'}) {
    return (

{work.map((post) => {
    const locations = post.node.caseStudyFeedLocations.nodes;
    return (
        <p key={post.node.slug}>
            {post.node.caseStudyTitle} in the{' '}
            {locations.map((location) => {
                return location.slug;
            })}{' '}
            location
        </p>
    );
})}

);
}
```

like..is there some easy way for me to predefine all these bits of info into shorter names so I don't have to write out `{post.node.caseStudyTitle}` and could just maybe write `{projectTitle}` in it's place? My best guess would be that I'd have to maybe write a function that transforms the returned data for the "work" items into some other type of object I could pass through something like `.map()`? I just don't know what that is called since I'm new to these languages.

Comment: _"write a function that transforms the returned data for the "work" items into some other type of object"_ - That seems like what you want in this case. Are you having any issues with writing that function?

Comment: Yes, I'm not entirely sure how to do that in this context, or how to tie it into my react component.